# Read text file character by character

Tags: java, arrays

I need help reading a character from a text file.
I want to read character by character and get the id of ecpace

Here is my code:

```
public class GenieL {
    String Nom_of_TACHE;
    int ID ;
    int time;
    Array table[];
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br=null;
        String strLine="";

        try {
            br=new BufferedReader (new FileReader("my.txt"));

            while((strLine=br.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println(strLine);
                Nom_of_TACHE=parseint(strLine);//
            } 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("Unable to find the file name ");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to read find the file name ");
        }
}}
```

Comment: read the file line by line and since every line is a String, do a for loop with the chars on it...

Comment: how do it that !!

Comment: Is it "write code for me question"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file line by line and since every line is a String, do a for loop with the chars on it...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("./Details.txt"), "UTF8"));

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Char at: " + line.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println("Another line");
    }
    br.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Reader.read` is your friend. It is documented with Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read().

Comment: Use this in conjunction with InputStreamReader and Charset to specify encoding and you'll achieve what you're looking for.